# Woocommerce number of rows per page

Tags: woocommerce

I'm using woocommerce since a while and I need to increase the displayed number of orders per page in admin panel.

There are only 20 rows per page and it is not enough for me.

I was looking for a plugin, but I can't find any. 
I also don't know what changes to do in the code info.

Maybe you have some experience with it?

Answer (score -1):

It is so easy: just go to the Orders page in admin panel, click "Screen Options" at the top right corner of the screen, and choose the number of orders to show. See details on this screenshot:

http://prntscr.com/ielc7l